aws rds describe-db-instances just hangs while other awscli commands work
In my EC2 aws rds describe-db-instances --region eu-west-1 just hangs, while aws ec2 describe-instances works, for example.
The EC2 IAM Role has the necessary permissions and all outbound connections are allowed.
Any ideas what else I could check?
IAM Role:
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "ec2:Describe*",
                "elasticfilesystem:DescribeFileSystems",
                "elasticfilesystem:ClientMount",
                "elasticfilesystem:ClientWrite",
                "rds:DescribeDBInstances",
                "ssm:GetParameter*",
                "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue",
                "kms:Decrypt",
                "rds:Describe*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}

aws rds describe-db-instances --region eu-west-1 --debug output, it just hangs:
2024-06-10 13:08:39,866 - MainThread - botocore.endpoint - DEBUG - Sending http request: <AWSPreparedRequest stream_output=False, method=POST, url=https://rds.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/, headers={'Content-Length': '45', 'X-Amz-Date': '20240610T130839Z', 'User-Agent': 'aws-cli/1.18.147 Python/2.7.18 Linux/4.14.344-262.563.amzn2.x86_64 botocore/1.18.6', 'X-Amz-Security-Token': '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', 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8', 'Authorization': 'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=ASIAZF5EJYRNGFQ736DQ/20240610/eu-west-1/rds/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=content-type;host;x-amz-date;x-amz-security-token, Signature=e34ef78e97ccafbeff86695506a10cc9e4e1d942848e41140c59beb3a836356d'}>
2024-06-10 13:08:39,867 - MainThread - urllib3.connectionpool - DEBUG - Starting new HTTPS connection (1): rds.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com:443


How does your request reach the AWS service endpoints? Does the EC2 instance have  a public IP and routes via IGW or do you have service-specific VPC endpoints?

It's an ECS task and there's an RDS VPC endpoint which is attached to the same 3 private subnets that the ECS tasks operate in. On the VPC I have hostnames enabled and the VPC endpoint has Private DNS names enabled.

But I'm not sure the aws cli command would be going through the VPC endpoint?

Turns out it was a very basic misconfigurations on my part. Security group had the wrong inboud rules. It was allowing port 3306, but that's for the security group of the database instance. The security group for the RDS VPC endpoint should allow traffic on port 443 from the VPC CIDR block or at least the private subnets it's attached to.
I've also enabled private DNS names. Not sure if that's needed for ECS task connectivity.
One simple way to test connectivity is to create an EC2 instance in the same private subnet as the ECS task and try the below. This does need private DNS names enabled to work.
curl https://api.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/


There's a number of DNS-related things you have to do in order to reach AWS service endpoints via a VPC interface endpoint.
